# Object contains other objects in yml to pojo

Tags: java, spring, properties, yaml, pojo

I have a yml file where I have defined all objects, in this dummmy example I have this java objects:

```
public class departament{
    private Product product;
    private String name;

}
```

```
public class product {
    private String name;
    private String id;
}
```

and this yml file, **important:** this file doesn't work, that represent very well that i want to do:

```
products:
    bottle:
      id: 1
      name: bottle
    apple:
      id: 2
      name: apple
      
departaments:
    departament_one:
        product: apple
        name: departamentName
    departament_two:
        product: bottle
        name: departamentName2
```

I want that when I read the yml file in my configurationPropertiesClass, I want to have a List of departaments and each departament has the product declared in the yml file.

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my english, it is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul repeat the object instead:

```
products:
    product:
      id: 1
      name: bottle
    product:
      id: 2
      name: apple
      
departaments:
    departament:
        product: apple
        name: departamentName
    departament:
        product: bottle
        name: departamentName2
```

Comment: Yes, but this solution in long file is too repetitive and generate plenty of duplicated code.
It is not possible how create a variable of product and use it in other object?

Comment: An i think in this solution, if the departaments pojos wos created from the yml they wouldn't contain the product object